# Unable to disable link-local auto configuration in Ubuntu 20.0.4.1 with netplan

Tags: netplan

After half a day of googling, searching, reading, adding/removing packages (mostly avahi things), trying/playing with netplan on this Ubuntu 20.04.1 test machine, I am unable to disable link-local auto configuration.

This is where I stand :

Linux kernel boot command line contains :

```
ipv6.disable=1
```

And

```
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop-minimal
...
sudo apt-get --assume-yes update ; sudo apt-get --assume-yes dist-upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
    network:
        ethernets:
            ens192:
                dhcp4: false
                dhcp6: false
                link-local: []
            ens162:
                dhcp4: false
                dhcp6: false
                link-local: []
        version: 2
```

If someone have any clue on where to start that would be great.

Thanks in advance,
have a nice day,
Mickael.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported as a bug in netplan at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1908028

Comment: Hello and thanks, but your link is not working for me. Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, that bug report had been incorrectly marked private. Fixed now.